# TensorFlow Object Detection API - determining FLOPS and number of Parameters

Tags: parameters, tensorflow2.0, object-detection, object-detection-api, flops

I have trained a custom SSD-MobileNetV2-FPN-Lite (320x320) from the TensorFlow Model zoo (TF2) and would like to know how many trainable parameters and FLOPs this network has. Does anyone know how to determine this?